# Doctrine 2.0 Hidration Array Result

Tags: sql, join, doctrine-orm

I have a lag on this query:

```
            $result = $qb->select("p,s,t,w,ph")
                      ->from("Entity\Property", "p")
                      ->innerJoin("p.sub_type","s")
                      ->innerJoin("s.type","t")
                      ->innerJoin("p.web_info","w")
                      ->leftJoin("p.photos","ph")
                      ->where("w.publish_on_trovit > 0")
                      ->andWhere("p.status=0")
                      ->add("orderBy","p.id ASC,ph.display_order ASC")
                      ->setFirstResult($offset)
                      ->setMaxResults($limit)
                      ->getQuery()
                      ->getArrayResult();
```

**The problem is the load of entiry entities**, and to solve the lag i need to select only needed table fields.

But when i use "p.id,ph.id" instead "p,ph" doctrine hidration change the result array to a flat table like a normal sql join.

**Have a way to load only needed fields in a parenet->chields result set like the result of above query?**

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Solved usin partial the tree struct is mantained:

```
select("partial p.{id,reference},partial ph.{id,name},partial t.{id,name},partial s.{id,name},partial w.{id}")
```

var_dump

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => int 9
      'reference' => string '9' (length=1)
      'sub_type' => 
        array
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => string 'Padrao' (length=6)
          'type' => 
            array
              ...
      'web_info' => 
        array
          'id' => int 9
      'photos' => 
        array
          empty
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => int 16
      'reference' => string '124793' (length=6)
      'sub_type' => 
        array
          'id' => int 1
          'name' => string 'Padrao' (length=6)
          'type' => 
            array
              ...
      'web_info' => 
        array
          'id' => int 16
      'photos' => 
        array
          empty
```